# Nested for loop in R is giving me bracket error despite using correct amount of brackets

Tags: r, for-loop

So I made a matrix with 4 rows to represent 4 individuals (each with an ID). I'm trying to use a nested for loop to incorporate a time increment in the first loop, then in the second loop add a row for every individual for the new time and incorporate a function in the 3rd column and each increase in time will add on the value of the function to the value in the same column from the function from the previous time step. I'm starting small with 4 individuals and 5 time steps, but for some reason I'm getting an error message about an unexpected '}', but I've gone through and double checked the brackets and parentheses multiple times. I'm not sure what the issue is with the for loop or if it's going to end up doing what I intend for it to do.

```
uptake <- function(x){
  vmax <- x[1]
  km <- x[2]
  s <- x[3]
  result <- vmax*(s/(km+s))
  return(result)
}

agents <- matrix(0, nrow = 4, ncol = 6)
colnames(agents) <- c("Time", "ID", "Uptake rate (V)", "vmax", "km", "s")
agents[,1] <- 0
agents[,2] <- c(1:4)
agents[,4] <- 1.4
agents[,5] <- 17
agents[,6] <- 1.4

for (i in seq(1, 5, 1)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(agents$Time = i-1)){
    agents[j,] <-rbind(agents, c(i, agents[j,2], agents[j,3] + 
                       uptake(agents[j,4:6]), agents[j,4], 
                       agents[j,5], agents[j,6]))}}
```

and this is the error code I'm getting:

```
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"                       uptake(agents[j,4:6]), agents[j,4], 
                       agents[j,5], agents[j,6]))}"
```

I appreciate any advice and insight!!

Comment: I don't have any data, the values are produced by the uptake function. Each individual will have the same values, I'm just trying to get the functionality working. The function produces the value around 0.107

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
for (i in seq(1, 5, 1)) {
  for (j in seq_len(sum(agents[,"Time"] == i - 1))) {
    agents <- rbind(
      agents,
      c(
        i,
        agents[j,2],
        agents[j,3] + uptake(agents[j,4:6]),
        agents[j,4], 
        agents[j,5],
        agents[j,6]
      )
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: YES! The only issue is that the value generated by the function is not being added to the value in the 3rd column from the previous time step. Do you know how to fix that?